# Get rid of location prompt in ios webview

Tags: ios, uiwebview, react-native

I use a webview (which shows separate website) in react native. This website shows a map on click. When I click "find my location" I get a permission prompt (iOS). I use `navigation.getCurrentPosition` in the main website, pass lat and lng variables into url and use those variables to identify my location inside the webview, so I know it is possible to prohibit this location prompt when variables are used. Does anyone know  how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Found the way to do it. Because in my app I use variables to identify location I just don't run navigation.getCurrenPosition when on the app. I still get variables to use but no prompt.